# Node NPM Install - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I'm behind a corporate firewall and I wish to use npm to install packages.

Initially when I ran the comand `npm install` i was getting proxy authentication error.

I then set the proxy config as below:

```
npm config set proxy http://"ninjadev:5trongP@ssw0rd"@proxy.some-bigcorp.com:PORT
```

Now I get all i keep getting is 500 internal server error. See example below:

```
npm : npm ERR! code E500
 At line:1 char:1
 + npm install
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm ERR! code E500:String) [], 
   RemoteException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

 npm

 ERR!
  500 Internal Server Error: node-sass@^4.5.3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I was getting the same error for another package after removing everything from dependencies of package-lock.json file. Putting it back from a back-up solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue and spend sometime to figure it out by testing from my lab network and personal network.

From corporate network sometimes you won't be able to properly resolve registry.npmjs.org, as in my case. Try doing a nslookup registry.npmjs.org.

To workaround the problem do the following.

```
dig registry.npmjs.org @1.1.1.1
```

Take any of the ip in the output and add to /etc/hosts

```
104.16.16.35 registry.npmjs.org
```

You should be good to go now.